# Cannot upload compiled app to Pebble Watch, but can connect

Tags: android, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

I'm working on an app between an Android phone and Pebble watch. Currently, I'm just trying to setup a basic `hello_world.c` app provided on cloudpebble.net, but I receive an "Unfortunately, Pebble has stopped working" error. The website will then say "Upload failed. No response from phone".

This is particularly bizarre because I have verified the connection between the phone, watch, and website through being able to take a screenshot of the watch face, which does not crash the app and works fine.

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 0):

I dont use cloudpebble, but the command line tool should work similar.
I found that installing an app compiled with an SDK Version > 3.7 on pebble watch with old firmware on classic pebble crashs the pebble app.